# Does EdgeNGram autocomplete_filter make sense with prefix search?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, search

i have Elastic Search Index with around 1 million records.
I want to do multi prefix search against 2 fields in the Elastic Search Index, Name and ID (there are around 10 total).
Does creating EdgeNGram autocomplete filter make sense at all?
Or i am missing the point of the EdgeNGram.
Here is the code i have for creation of the index:

```
client.indices.create({
    index: 'testing',
    // type: 'text',
    body: {
     settings: {
      analysis: {
        filter: {
          autocomplete_filter: {
            type: 'edge_ngram',
            min_gram: 3,
            max_gram: 20
          }
        },
        analyzer: {
          autocomplete: {
            type: 'custom',
            tokenizer: 'standard',
            filter: [
              'lowercase',
              'autocomplete_filter'
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
},function(err,resp,status) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else {
    console.log("create",resp);
  }
});
```

Code for searching

```
client.search({  
  index: 'testing',
  type: 'article',
  body: {
    query: {
        multi_match : {
          query:    "87041",
          fields: [ "name", "id" ],
          type: "phrase_prefix"
        }
      }
  }
},function (error, response,status) {
    if (error){
      console.log("search error: "+error)
    }
    else {
      console.log("--- Response ---");
      console.log(response);
      console.log("--- Hits ---");
      response.hits.hits.forEach(function(hit){
        console.log(hit);
      })
    }
});
```

The search returns the correct results, so my question being does creating the edgengram filter and analyzer make sense in this case?
Or this prefix functionality would be given out of the box?
Thanks a lot for your info

Comment: Well the solutions below dont match my real observation, but it is working fine as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

It is depending on your use case. Let me explain.

1. You can use `ngram` for this feature. Let's say your data is `london bridge`, then if your min gram is 1 and max gram is 20, it will be tokenized as `l, lo, lon, etc..` 
   Here the advantage is that even if you search for `bridge` or any `tokens which is part of the generated ngrams`, it will be matched.
2. There is one `out of box feature completion suggester`. It uses FST model to store them. Even the documentation says `it is faster to search but costlier to build`. But the think is it is `prefix suggester`. Meaning searching `bridge` will not bring `london bridge` by default. But there are ways to make this work. Workaround to achieve is that, to have array of tokens. Here `london bridge` and `bridge` are the tokens.
3. There is one more called `context suggester`. If you know that you are going to search on `name` or `id`, it is best over completion suggester. As completion suggester works over on all the index, context suggester works on a particular index based on the context.

As you say, it is prefix search you can go for completion. And you mentioned that there 10 such fields. And if you know the field to be suggested at fore front, then you can go for context suggester.

[one nice answer about edge ngram and completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542913/when-is-the-analysis-chain-created-for-edge-n-gram-in-elasticsearch)

[completion suggester for middle of the words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178565/partial-matching-from-middle-in-completion-suggestion-elasticsearch) - I used this solution, it works like charm.

You can refer documentation for other default options available within suggesters.

Comment: Regarding approach 2) If the name is ```london bridge```, even if i search for lon, lond, bridg, bri, etc it brings up the term. I assume this approach is available out of the box without any configuration after you create the index with elastic search 7.8.1.
From what i can see, the ```array of tokens``` you are mentioning seems to be available out of the box. Correct me if i am wrong @Gibbs?

Comment: Yes, but the tokens is not out of the box. It supports array of strings as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Sorry but i still can't understand your thought. How come the search in the code works when the  tokens are not available out of the box?

Comment: I will tell you. You need to have ingest pipeline which will describe how to tokenixe. When you insert a document it ll be stored as an array. So that you can search on any words which will work as prefix search. [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281609/elasticsearch-split-by-comma-split-filter-logstash) One of our SO expert helped me. It is similar to this.